# sshでログインした環境でコマンドの実行結果をファイルに出力するには

Tags: macos, bash

環境
    Mac1(192.168.0.5) ----------Mac2(192.168.0.10)

において
    ssh hoge@192.168.0.10

した環境上でログインされたMac、シェルスクリプトを実行する予定です。

サーバ側で

```
iperf -c 192.168.0.5
```

は実行できましたが

```
iperf -c 192.168.0.5 >>hoge.txt
```

としたところ、問題が発生しました。
ただしくファイルを出力するにはどうすればよいでしょうか。

実際の動作

```
error: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

期待した動作

```
hoge.txtが出力される
```

Comment: リダイレクトを追加しただけでホストの名前解決ができなくなる (IPv4 アドレスを書いているのに) のは不思議ですね。 `192.168.0.5` と `>>hoge.txt` の間が全角スペースだったりしないでしょうか?

Comment: シェルスクリプトの失敗するコマンドラインだけでなく、すべてを載せられないでしょうか。予想ですが何らかの理由により ‘getaddrinfo‘(3) が失敗していると思われます。Mac OS X って `ltrace`(1) か相当するコマンドはありませんかね。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

本家SOにも似たような質問がありました。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252294/

恐らくSSHの実行時のポートの問題だったりしないのかなぁと思います。
`ssh -p 22 hoge@192.168.0.10`か、
`ssh -l hoge -p 22 192.168.0.10`ではどうでしょうか？

Answer (score 3):

iperfを実行したタイミングでエラーになるということでいいですかね。だとするとsshで接続しているのは無関係です。

提示されているエラーはホスト名の解決に失敗したときのものです。IPアドレスを指定しているように見えますが、実際には何かが違うのではないでしょうか。

```
コメントで指摘されているように空白が全角になっている。
% iperf -c　192.168.1.1　>> ...
          ^^           ^^
error: hostname nor servname provided, or not known

IPアドレスとしてあり得ない値
% iperf -c 192.168.1.999
error: hostname nor servname provided, or not known

ピリオドがカンマになっている
% iperf -c 192.168.1,1
error: hostname nor servname provided, or not known

全角ピリオドが混じっている
% iperf -c 192.168.1．1
error: hostname nor servname provided, or not known
```

Answer (score 1):

不思議な現象ですね。
特に根拠もなく、タダの感ですが、bash の構文を変えてみて動作が変わるか試して見て下さい。

```
iperf -c 192.168.0.5 >> hoge.txt

(iperf -c 192.168.0.5) >> hoge.txt

bash -c "iperf -c 192.168.0.5" >> hoge.txt

echo "iperf -c 192.168.0.5" | bash >> hoge.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

「5」が file descriptor と解釈されたと考えて、

```
iperf -c '192.168.0.5' >>hoge.txt
```

でいかがでしょうか。